# Denial of Service attack for One Time Password resend function

Tags: security, brute-force, owasp, denial-of-service, web-application-firewall

In our web application, we have a function where the user reset his/her password. Part of the process requires sending OTP via SMS. The thing is, we have a function  in our page that allows user to resend the OTP in case it was not received due to certain reasons (sms provider error, network error etc.). Upon recent penetration testing, it was found that that the back end call for sending the OTP is vulnerable for DoS attacks. Hackers can run it to flood users with SMS.

We already have a mechanism in our firewall which detects automated attacks for denial of service. The problem is, there is a minimum limit of requests per second for the  firewall classifies it as an attack. (e.g. 100 requests per second, the FW blocks it but anything below, it allows).

Lets say hacker did a program to resend otp via sms per second, the firewall would not be able to detect it. Another option we can do is handle it programatically but we can't think of a best way to do it. Can anyone advise us on this? We can't just limit the no of times an OTP can be resend because we are worried of its effect in user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things come to my mind:

Take Macuistin's idea but make the timeouts grow over time.  I know I wouldn't want 3 text messages a minute.  After X number of messages don't send anymore and have them contact support.  If this is a legitimate user, after so many messages something isn't right and you should just stop.

How about adding a step before this, send a link to the email address of the user with a one-time link, click on the link will send them to the page to enter in the OTP that triggered on the link (there could be a resend link on there as well which would not trigger another email).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the timings in real world use cases?

For example, if a real user takes 20 seconds before pressing retry then you could add that restriction to your service without real users knowing that the restriction is in place.
That doesn't mean that you couldn't accept another request before this time, it could just be queued until the timeout has passed.

Answer (score 0):

This will not possible through WAF, Here you can use **Captcha** for failed attempts. 
Captcha only pop up when particular limit cross. You can set limit on IP, UserID, and session variable.